# Stopping/Interrupting an operation

Tags: java, parsing, operation, cancel-button

I have a Java project that parses an html page using JSoup and writes some dates in an Excel spreadsheet (`.xls` file).

In the frame there is a button "Stop operation" so the user can stop the task but the button does not work until the parsing/writing has ended.
"X button" in the frame has the same behavior.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: How are you currently trying to stop it?

Comment: This is quite a broad question.  What have you tried?

Comment: 1. Please don't write "in Java" in the title. It's enough when it's tagged as Java. 2. What have you tried so far? What sources did you try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all the parsing and writing operation in an external thread, and then interrupt the thread if the user clicks on the Stop Operation button.

Here's an example on how you can use the Thread interruption: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_interrupt.htm

Comment: If an external thread doesn't work, e.g. because the operation cannot be interrupted, you will need to put it in another process, which you can kill.

Comment: Interrupting the thread doesn't necessarily do anything though; you'd have to implement logic in that thread to deal with the interruption appropriately.

Comment: Using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` isn't very reliable, as there are many things which may clear the interrupted status of a thread.  It's better to use a `volatile boolean` flag which the worker method should periodically check to see whether it should stop.

Comment: You are right. For sure, using a volatile boolean to ask if the thread can be interrupted seems a good alternative for a clean code. And of course, the Thread being interrupted should implement some logic to handle the interruption. But that is shown quite clearly in the linked example.

Comment: @javatutorial The linked example is horrendous.  The `work2` method will only enter the `if` block once the thread has been interrupted (the if should probably be `if ( ! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() )` - note the `!`).  Until then, it just sits in a busy wait, continuously going through `while (true)`.

Comment: Indeed. But it shows how to handle thread interruptions and InterruptedExceptions, and that was what the OP needed. An example is not an application, but it can be helpful.
"HelloWorld" anyone? ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that what you've done is to put the long-running code on the main thread. If you do this, there's no way that your buttons can interact with the work and stop it.

You'll need to move the work onto another thread, and then have that thread check periodically (after each small unit of work, for instance) whether it's been politely asked to stop (by setting a flag, marked as `volatile` so that the thread doesn't cache the value and not see the update).

Make sure you don't fall into the trap of using `Thread.stop()` for this, which is deprecated, and for good reason. You need to make sure that your worker thread co-operates with the main thread to stop when it's asked to.